# Executing Javascript with php and echo some vars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to execute a simple javascript file with if and else in php. So far it is working but i have an issue.. See the example bellow.

```
<?
$varone = "Popup One";
$vartwo = "Popup Two";

if ($_GET['myrequest'] == "")
{

echo <<<html
<script>
alert($varone);
</script>
html;

}else{

echo <<<html
<script>
alert($vartwo);
</script>
html;

}
?>
```

So i want to pass my php variables inside each alert! Or is there any other simply way to execute my javascript and pass my php variables in javascript?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Php is server side and javascript is client side.

Comment: @Deepu javascript is not server side! It's client side.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<?php
    $varone = "Popup One";
   $vartwo = "Popup Two";

  if ($_GET['myrequest'] == "")
   {

echo " <script>
         alert('".$varone."');
       </script>";

}else{

     echo "<script>
        alert('".$vartwo."');
      </script>  ";

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to add single quotes in the alerts: `echo "<script>
        alert('".$vartwo."');
      </script>  ";`

Answer (score 1):

To Keep separate your JavaScript and PHP try this

```
<?php
$varone = "Popup One";
$vartwo = "Popup Two";

if ($_GET ['myrequest'] == "") {
    ?>
      <script>
         alert('<?php echo  $varone; ?>');
       </script>
<?php
} else {
    ?>
       <script>
        alert('<?php echo  $vartwo; ?>');
      </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing quotes around your variables inside the alerts.

Try this:

```
<?
$varone = "Popup One";
$vartwo = "Popup Two";

if ($_GET['myrequest'] == "")
{

    echo <<<html
    <script>
        alert('$varone');
    </script>
    html;

} else {

    echo <<<html
    <script>
        alert('$vartwo');
    </script>
    html;

}
?>
```

You may have spotted this javascript error if you had looked in your browser's javascript console, which is very helpful for debugging. Google for how to open the javascript console in whichever web browser you use.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you're trying to achieve but i think that if you want to pass some var from php to js the best approach would be  use $.ajax , but this depend on what your trying to do or in this case maybe something like this should do the tricks.

```
  <?php
   if($_GET['myrequest'] == ""){
       $alertVar = "popupone";
   }
   else{
       $alertVar = "popuptwo";
   }
   ?>

      <script>
         alert('<?php echo $alertVar ?>');
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few choices as seen in the answers.

```
<?php

$varone = "Popup One";
$vartwo = "Popup Two";

?>

<script>
<?php if ($_GET['myrequest'] == ""):?>
    alert('<?php echo $varone; ?>');
<?php else: ?>
    alert('<?php echo $vartwo; ?>');
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
```